# Brownie "No Module named"Users"" error

Tags: solidity, python, brownie, visual-studio-code

I keep on getting this error, following the Freecodecamp solidity tutorial. Brownie seems to be fine when making the accounts and adding private key like seen in video, and ganache-cli is installed securely, but this doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions

[image]

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68721661/eth-brownie-no-module-named-users-someuser

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, I might need more information (just finished the same tutorial you are going through).

What network are you trying to deploy to? If you're only accessing a local ganache chain, it should work just fine. The problem with this code would arise when trying to deploy to testnet.

As per brownie documentation:

`The Accounts container (available as accounts or just a) allows you to access all your local accounts.`

Local accounts only meana those mock accounts on your local chain. To add your existing account on a testnet, you need to get your public and private key from your (Metamask?) wallet and somehow import them to brownie.

There are two safe ways to do it:

**1) Without needing to provide password on every transaction. (Kinda safe)**

Using `brownie-config.yaml`

```
dotenv: .env

wallets:
  from_key: ${PRIVATE_KEY}
```

and `.env`

```
export PRIVATE_KEY = 0x0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123
```

Be sure to exclude this `.env` file from any version control using `.gitignore`!!! Pushing this to GIT would be catastrophic as there's the same private key for testnet and mainnet in metamask! To be completely safe, I would suggest to create a new metamask account and use it only for testnets.

**2) Providing password on every transaction. (Super safe)**

Brownie allows to import your private key and hash it using your password:

`brownie accounts new <your-account-id>`

Now when accessing the account from brownie, accounts[0] is not sufficient. As recommended in the course, you'll need to create a helper function to get a proper account depending on the chain used.

```
from brownie import accounts, config


def get_account(index=None):
    if index:
        return accounts[index]
    if not is_local_chain():
        return accounts[0]
    else:
        # for use with method 1)
        # return accounts.add(config["wallets"]["from_key"])
        # for use with method 2)
        # return accounts.load("your-account-id")
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. At this point in the tutorial I'm at the point where we are geting started with Brownie. And I am deploying to a local ganache-cli

Comment: In that case I'm sorry, but I don't know an answer to your question. I've incorrectly assumed, that you are trying to use accounts[0] for a testnet.

As you've not yet configured brownie nor added any chains or accounts, the first thing I would try to completelely remove and reinstall brownie and all associated packages according to the Freecodecamp course.